# Command line arguments, printing columns and rows

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to print out characters given input from the command-line arguments. I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around this.

When I run ./test Foo bar I want it to print

```
./test
Foo
o
o

bar
a
r
```

While it might not be the best solution, I want it to be done using arrays of arrays of chars, and it looks like a three-dimensional array, so I'm going with a triple-nested for-loop.
What I have so far is this:

```
for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < argv[argc][j]; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < argv[argc][j]; k++) {
            printf("%c", k);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The outermost loop starts at 1, since I don't want to print out the `./test`-bit. But I'm lost. I can work with two-dimensional arrays, but I wanted to try it out with an extra dimension.

Can you give me a few pointers?

Comment: I'm not getting why you used the 3rd nested loop where it can be done in 2 loops?

Comment: Same ^. Also, what is the problem? You say what you want to do, but not what that code does for you

Comment: I'd bet money that it's doing something undefined because you're not doing anything to check if you're passing the end of the argument string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition(`j < argv[argc][j]`, `k < argv[argc][j]`) are wrong.

fix like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        puts(argv[i]);
        if(i){
            for(int j = 1; argv[i][j]; ++j){
                printf("%c\n", argv[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in 2 loops as

```
for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    for (j = 0; argv[i][j]!='\0'; j++) {
        printf("%c", argv[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: What is this `j < argv[argc][j]!='\0'` ??

Comment: It's a mistake. I changed it. Thank you @artm

Comment: Yah. Got you @artm Now checkout